# ng2-translate: Is there any way to use default lang in case of Missing Translations?

Tags: angular, module, internationalization, ng2-translate

I am using angular2 rc5 and for i18n ng2-translate.

I want MissingTranslationHandler to automatically fall down to default language rather than providing explicit translations for missing values .

Is it possible to do in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution, it's probably not the best, but it works.   It simply looks up the message manually from the en.json file.  I tried using `params.translateService.currentLang` and `params.translateService.getDefaultLang()` to implement this but they were always `undefined` for some reason :(

```
import { MissingTranslationHandler, MissingTranslationHandlerParams } from 'ng2-translate';

let enBundle = require('../../assets/data/i18n/en.json');

export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {

  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
    return enBundle[params.key];
  }

}
```